# How to Parallelize a Function Efficiently

Tags: parallelization

I have a Mathematica function that I call a great many times in a notebook, as shown below.  What the function does is try to identify the optimal combination of stop loss and profit target for a bracket order trade, following a signal.

The core function looks like this:

```
 TradeProfit[dsPrices_, profitTarget_, stopLoss_] := 
 Module[{closePrices, highPrices, lowPrices, indPT, indSL, indFinal, 
   initialprice, finalprice, PL, exitCode}, 
  closePrices = dsPrices[[All, "Close"]] // Normal;
  highPrices = dsPrices[[All, "High"]] // Normal // Rest;
  lowPrices = dsPrices[[All, "Low"]] // Normal // Rest;
  initialprice = First@closePrices;
  indPT = 
   Position[UnitStep[highPrices - (initialprice + profitTarget)], 
       1] /. {} -> {Length@closePrices} // First // Plus[#, 1] &;
  indSL = 
   Position[UnitStep[(initialprice - stopLoss) - lowPrices], 
       1] /. {} -> {Length@closePrices} // First // Plus[#, 1] &;
  indFinal = Min[{indPT, indSL, Length@closePrices}];
  exitCode = 
   If[indFinal == Length@closePrices, 0, 
    If[MemberQ[indPT, indFinal], 1, 2]];
  finalprice = closePrices[[indFinal]];
  If[exitCode == 1, 
   finalprice = Min[{finalprice, (initialprice + profitTarget)}]];
  If[exitCode == 2, 
   finalprice = Min[{finalprice, (initialprice - stopLoss)}]];
  PL = finalprice - initialprice;
  {<|"PL" -> PL, "Initial Price" -> initialprice, 
    "Final Price" -> finalprice, "Exit Period" -> indFinal, 
    "Exit Code" -> exitCode, "Profit Target" -> profitTarget, 
    "Stop Loss" -> stopLoss|>}]
```

A test run using standard code takes about 0.27 secs:

```
x = Tuples[{Range[106, 110], Range[4, 20], Range[3, 6]}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[TradeProfit[dsPrices1Min[x[[i, 1]] + Range[120], All], 
     x[[i, 2]], x[[i, 3]]], {i, 10}] // Flatten // Dataset]
```

[image]

However, when I change the Table function to ParallelTable, it times out and I have to abort:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ParallelTable[TradeProfit[dsPrices1Min[x[[i, 1]] + Range[120], All], 
     x[[i, 2]], x[[i, 3]]], {i, 10}] // Flatten // Dataset]
```

Can anyone suggest the reason why, and how I could remedy the problem?

As I mentioned in my comments, I reckon the issue is passing around large chunks of data to multiple kernels for processing.  dsPrices1Min is a dataset of open/high/low/close prices, which is often large.

I tried a simplified version of the code, pre-extracting the required prices from the dataset, as follows:

```
 hp = dsPrices1Min[x[[1, 1]] + Range[120], "High"] // Normal // Rest;
lp = dsPrices1Min[x[[1, 1]] + Range[120], "Low"] // Normal // Rest;
cp = dsPrices1Min[x[[1, 1]] + Range[120], "Close"] // Normal;
```

And then:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[TradeProfit2[cp, hp, lp, x[[i, 2]], x[[i, 3]]], {i, 10}] // 
    Flatten // Dataset // Quiet]
```

[image]

But the ParallelTable version is considerably slower:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ParallelTable[
     TradeProfit2[cp, hp, lp, x[[i, 2]], x[[i, 3]]], {i, 10}] // 
    Flatten // Dataset // Quiet]
```

[image]

As I said, I am fairly sure that the issue is passing around large chunks of data.  If anyone has any suggestions of a better method for dealing with the issue, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Without example inputs, it will be nearly impossible to help you. Also, please try to simplify the example as much as possible - I'm sure you can remove a lot of stuff while still keeping the problematic behavior. As for the optimization, the first step is always to figure out which line is actually the problem. Try to wrap each part in `AbsoluteTiming[...]`, and see where the most time is spent. Only then does it make sense to try and optimize something

Comment: Hard to understand what you want to do when the posted code does not define your functions: `plStatsNullEntry`, `FirstInSequence`, `TradeProfit` or  `final`.   Maybe just me, but I also find your use of Postfix (//) sometimes as much as 4 times in a line of code confusing.

Comment: Further not clear on your use of `CompoundExpression` (`;`) in places where I don't think you need it e.g., just after `Goto[final]` in `If[Length[rawsignals] == 0,
  PLstats = plStatsNullEntry; Goto[final];
  ];`  You do the same thing in a number of other `If[...]`s.  Not certain what this does for you.  Any of this could trip you up.

Comment: I have simplified the code to focus on the core of the problem.  Something in the TradeProfit function doesn't parallelize well.

Comment: What is the function `dsPrices1Min`?

Comment: dsPrices1Min is a dataset of Open,High,Low,Close prices

Comment: So I reckon that the issue is to do with passing around copies of large chunks of data to multiple kernels for processing.

Comment: For anyone interested in the issue, the problem does indeed seem to be passing large chunks to data between kernels, especially in dataset format:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1667335

Comment: Hmmm...?  Rather than distributing the entire data sets to every kernel, I wonder if one could send different chunks of the data to specific kernels for processing, then assemble the results on the controlling kernel.  Just a thought.

Comment: Is there a published paper/note regarding the mathematical background of what you are doing in finance? Maybe, it helps more for understanding what your code is.